# Can I use the whole native project in react native with native UI?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to re-use my whole native Chat project in react native Project along with its native UI components.Is it possible?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First create original account :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Of course you can get the native project architecture, But you have to manually do majority of the coding in react native project. Specially in UI .Because in native project it is xml layouts.

Comment: any way it could be possible? As given in docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios they are using native IOS  UI in react native. Isn't it possible in android?

Answer (score 0):

Technically its not possible. If that were the case there wouldn't have been the need to invent react native in the first place. If you go through the documentation and try to understand how react native works you'd understand the difference.
The Native code is Java or Swift but what you write code in RN is JavaScript, React Native architecture is the bridge between both of these. I recommend reading How RN works ([Read this](https://medium.com/we-talk-it/react-native-what-it-is-and-how-it-works-e2182d008f5e)). What you're asking is impossible.